# Which with vectors sometimes works - R

Tags: r

Why does this example work:

```
which(letters %in% c('j', 'e', 'f', 'f', 'r', 'e', 'y'))
```

However; this one does not?

```
name <- c(strsplit("jeffrey", ""))
which(letters %in% name)
```

Isn't this the exact same thing since in both instance the second argument in the which function is a vector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that the `strsplit` is still a `list` of `length` 1 with the first element a `vector`

```
strsplit("jeffrey", "")
#[[1]]
#[1] "j" "e" "f" "f" "r" "e" "y"
```

Wrapping with `c` is not going to change the scenario as by default `recursive = FALSE`.

```
c(strsplit("jeffrey", ""))
#[[1]]
#[1] "j" "e" "f" "f" "r" "e" "y"
```

Changing the `recursive = TRUE` will make it possible to convert the `list` to a `vector`

```
c(strsplit("jeffrey", ""), recursive = TRUE)
#[1] "j" "e" "f" "f" "r" "e" "y"
```

If we use `unlist` (as in @JohnyCrunch's solution), it unlists the `list` because by default `recursive = TRUE` and convert to `vector`.  In our case, another approach would be to extract the `list` element with `[[` (as it is only a `list` of `length` 1.

```
name <- strsplit("jeffrey", "")[[1]]
which(letters %in% name)
#[1]  5  6 10 18 25
```

Comment: You mention `unlist` but then you use something that looks like array notation `[[1]]`?

Comment: @smykes Yes, I was updating it then I find JohnyCrunch came up with `unlist`.  So to avoid redundancy, I didn't specify it

Answer (score 3):

If you run `class(name)` you will note that it is a list. Use `unlist()`to solve the problem:

```
name <- unlist(strsplit("jeffrey", ""))
which(letters %in% name)
```

Best!

Comment: I just noticed this only outputs unique numbers, would I want `match` to get all numbers?

Comment: I have noticed once name is converted a vector `match(name,letters)` will return each value.